# Fork Of Github Pages Repo redirects to the original site

Tags: github-pages

I found a nice unblocked games website but it's spreading around and the school is about to block it. Obviously I forked the repo, and deployed on GitHub pages (the original was also using GitHub Pages).

When I go to the website everything's fine, but when I click on any of the games it redirects me back to the original site (for example I'm on the site, https://drakonix1050.github.io/peterpanlostinneverland.github.io/, I click on a game and it goes to Sz-games.github.io/(that game).

When I replace `Sz-games.github.io` with `drakonix1050.github.io/peterpanlostinneverland.github.io` the game works. Here's the site:

https://drakonix1050.github.io/peterpanlostinneverland.github.io/

Does anyone know how I can fix it?

I edited the HTML for some of the games and replaced every part in the code that said `Sz-games.github.io`. I waited for the changes to take effect and nothing happened. The game didn’t break but it still opened in the wrong link.

Comment: Not sure if you've configured this yet, but you should be able to go to your repo **Settings** and go to the **Pages** tab. This is where the actual GH Pages deployments are handled. If this hasn't been updated, I believe your site won't have self-published. From there, you can set how it deploys (eg. from a branch or via GitHub Actions). 

[Here's more info in GH's docs](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site)

Comment: Yeah. I’ve done that already though.